# Channel trait in google actions for smart media devices

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I have been to trying out the [google home nodejs sample project](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs). I am facing some difficulties to make `action.devices.traits.Channel` trait work for one of my home projects where I am adding a device of type `action.devices.types.SETTOP`. I have also tried the same with `action.devices.types.REMOTECONTROL` and `action.devices.types.TV` but the `action.devices.commands.selectChannel` command and params are never reaching the /smarthome fulfilment function in firebase. However, `action.devices.commands.relativeChannel` and `action.devices.commands.returnChannel` seem to work in the expected way.

Comment: Does your payload properly contain either the `channelNumber` or `channelCode` matching one of the `availableChannels` Are you seeing any errors in your project logs?

Comment: Hi Amitmula can you please share sample code for device `action.devices.types.SETTOP`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77109719/google-action-smart-home-set-top-box-sample

Answer (score 1):

Similar situation here.  Implementing local home sdk for set top box.

In my case, I could receive the request with:

```
'change to {ABC} on {my stb name}'
```

However, it sends me 'action.devices.commands.InitiateMedia' instead and response with 'Got it, {ABC} on spotify playing on {my stb name}'.

```
 * {ABC} is defined in availableChannels
```

If you don't link with music service, can you try above command and share the result?